# Can I buy a voucher for chips at a Las Vegas casino, from an online website?

Tags: online-resources, las-vegas

My brother will travel to the United States next summer and he plans to spend two nights in Las Vegas. I'm sure he and his friends would be delighted to play a bit in a casino and I would like to make it possible by "reserving" some chips for him for Christmas.

Do you think it is possible for me to reserve some online (outside the US) so that they have some kind of voucher to show in exchange for chips when they arrive in Vegas ? If so, could you recommend me trustworthy websites on which I could make the reservation ?

Comment: I'll be pretty surprised if this is possible.  Casino chips are basically equivalent to cash, so any system for sending / "reserving" casino chips would effectively be a money transfer service, like Western Union, and would be subject to all the same fraud and regulatory concerns, while having a much smaller customer base.  As such, I think your best option would be to simply give him cash, and let him buy chips when he arrives.

Comment: In other words, the "voucher" you are seeking looks like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7b/Obverse_of_the_series_2009_%24100_Federal_Reserve_Note.jpg/320px-Obverse_of_the_series_2009_%24100_Federal_Reserve_Note.jpg).

Comment: You cannot obtain chips outside of a casino, or remotely, but you can buy gift certificates, online. They're not generic; you would have to do it directly with a specific casino in Vegas.

Comment: Thank you @Giorgio! I think this is what I am looking for. I'm going to check this out.

Comment: @NateEldredge This would be an extremely impersonal gift. It's as if I told him: "I didn't know what to offer so I'm just giving you cash". I think I will have to think of another gift then... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Giorgio: Are you sure about the gift certificates / cards, and if so, can you post some links? In particular, are you certain that you can get certificates that can be used to buy chips? I searched for "[casino name] gift certificate" for a few of the big casinos, and I found either (a) no results, (b) dodgy third-party sites selling generic Visa gift cards, or (c) official gift cards with disclaimers "cannot be used for gaming".

Comment: @NateEldredge I looked at [Bellagio](https://order.cardgistics.com/Cart.aspx?customerid=212A1193&productid=8CE094&cardimageid=3afoy8x93&customimage=false) and [MGM Resorts](https://www2.mgmresorts.com/giftofvegas/) and there doesn't seem to be a restriction. However, you could be right if it is a VISA gift card; if it's a VISA debit card you should be able to get cash from an ATM or a Casino cashier (and you're never far from an ATM in casinos).

Comment: @Giorgio: The Bellagio one doesn't look like the official site (unless it is an authorized third-party vendor and you followed a link from the official site).  The MGM one has a note in the fine print: "MGM Resorts International Gift Cards are not refundable or redeemable for cash, credit or **gaming activity**."

Comment: @NateEldredge I did, on the Ballagio, linking from [this page on its site](https://www.bellagio.com/en/amenities/guest-services.html).  Why don't you answer this question, I'll delete my comments, and then upvote your info? The bottom line is that Gift Cards cannot be used for cash; prepaid debit cards can.

Comment: Giving cash with an aim does not make a difference from giving a gift card or a voucher, but does allow the person getting it to not spend it on the intended purpose. Maybe your brother decides not to visit Vegas, or feels that gambling is not for him (for many reasons, addiction risk being one.) If you give cash with a cover for the place you think he should spend it, he can still use if for something else.

Comment: The absolute last thing casinos want to do is operate a system where they're responsible for paying out large amounts of random cash to/from strangers. [They won't even pay out their own chips](https://lasvegassun.com/news/2007/mar/09/chips-no-longer-good-cash/) if they don't think you got them gambling there. They have no way of knowing whether that voucher is going to be spent on gambling or turned right back into cash and walked out the door, at which point they could have just facilitated money laundering.

Answer (score 2):

Contact the casino in question directly.  Explain to them your motivation.  It is possible they can make arrangements directly with you to fund his gambling activity up to a certain amount.

Note that in order to do this, the amount might need to be significant.  If the intention is just a few hundred dollars or less, it will be more practical to give him US cash.